# Integral with an undefined point

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I was asked to integrate $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^1 g(x)\,dx$, where $g(x) = \dfrac{d}{dx} \left( \dfrac{1}{1+2^{1/x}} \right)$. If function $g$ had been defined on $x = 0$, for example $g(0) = 0$ or another value, then I could have said that $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^1 g(x)\,dx = \dfrac{2}{3}$. Can I have the same result otherwise? 
Note: definite integral is based under Riemann's approach.

Comment: Riemann integrability and the value of he integral do no change if you change the value of the function at a finite number of points.

Comment: True, but in this case $g(0)$ is undefined.

Comment: If it's undefined at a finite number of points then you ignore those points? So you can do: $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^1 g(x)\,dx =  \lim_{a\to 0^-}\int_{-1}^a g(x)\,dx + \lim_{b\to 0^+}\int_{b}^1 g(x)\,dx$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that $\frac{1}{1+2^{1/x}}$ is not continuous at $0$. Define
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{1+2^{1/x}}-1&\text{ if }x<0\\
0&\text{ if } x=0\\
\frac{1}{1+2^{1/x}}&\text{ if }x>0
\end{cases}$$
Then $f(x)$ is $C^\infty$ and $f'(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$ (here I'm assuming $g(0)$ is defined as $0$).

So $$\int_{-1}^1g(x)\,dx=\int_{-1}^1 f'(x)\,dx=f(1)-f(-1)=\tfrac{1}{3}-(-\tfrac{1}{3})=\tfrac{2}{3}$$

Comment: So in my case the value of the integral won't exist, unless I define $g(0)$?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the integral won't be defined. But if you were asked to calculate it, you can use common sense and define it at $0$ (as you please, since it doesn't matter).